# Is there a way to generate real time depthmap from single camera video in python/opencv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, esp32

I'm trying to **convert single images into it's depthmap**, but I can't find any useful tutorial or documentation.

I'd like to use opencv, but if you know a way to get the depth map using for example tensorflow, I'd be glad to hear it.

There are numerous tutorials for stereo vision but I want to make it cheaper because it's for a project to help blind people.

I'm currently using esp32 cam to stream frame by frame and receiving the images on python using opencv.

Comment: Depth is going to be difficult unless you have images from different locations on the same target. Depth isn't possible to calculate from a single image with no reference, as the image lacks a third dimension. If you have a single camera which is moving, you can do this by looking at historical data, but a single stationary camera will be difficult. It's why people with one eye have bad depth perception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, we need a **photometric** measurement from a different position in the world to form a **geometric** understanding of the world(a.k.a depth map). For a single image, it is not possible to measure the geometric, but it is possible to infer depth from prior understanding.

**One way** for a single image to work is to use a deep learning-based method to direct infer depth. Usually, the deep learning-based approaches are all based on python, so if you only familiar with **python**, then this is the approach that you should go for. If the image is small enough, i think it is possible for **realtime** performance. There are many of this kind of work using CAFFE, TF, TORCH etc. you can search on git hub for more option. The one I posted here is what i used recently

[image]

reference:
Godard, Clément, et al. "Digging into self-supervised monocular depth estimation." Proceedings of the IEEE international conference on computer vision. 2019.

Source code: https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2

**The other way** is to use a large FOV video for a single camera-based SLAM. This one has various constraints such as need good features, large FOV, slow motion, etc.  You can find many of this work such as DTAM, LSDSLAM, DSO, etc. There are a couple of other packages from HKUST or ETH that does the mapping given the position(e.g if you have GPS/compass), some of the famous names are REMODE+SVO open_quadtree_mapping etc.

One typical example for  a single camera-based SLAM would be LSDSLAM. It is a **realtime** SLAM.

This one is implemented based on ROS-C++, I remember they do publish the depth image. And you can write a **python** node to subscribe to the depth directly or the global optimized point cloud and project it into a depth map of any view angle.

[image]

reference: Engel, Jakob, Thomas Schöps, and Daniel Cremers. "LSD-SLAM: Large-scale direct monocular SLAM." European conference on computer vision. Springer, Cham, 2014.

source code: https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam

Answer (score 1):

To get fast and accurate results (at a certain level), you can refer to this notebook implementation of the depth estimation from the mono image. The Hugging Face framework provides it.

https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/DPT/DPT_inference_notebook_(depth_estimation).ipynb

Also, you check the link below for other open-source implementations.
https://paperswithcode.com/task/monocular-depth-estimation