# Lane tracking with a camera: how to get distance from camera to the lane?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, hough-transform

i am doing final year project as lane tracking using a camera. the most challenging task now is how i can measure distance between the camera (the car that carries it actually) and the lane.

While the lane is easily recognized (Hough line transform) but i found no way to measure distance to it.

given the fact that there is a way to measure distance to object in front of camera based on Pixel width of the object, but it does not work here be because the nearest point of the line, is blind in the camera.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to directly infer the depth map with a monocular camera.
You can refer my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687551/11530294

---

Usually, we need a **photometric** measurement from a different position in the world to form a **geometric** understanding of the world(a.k.a depth map). For a single image, it is not possible to measure the geometric, but it is possible to infer depth from prior understanding.

**One way** for a single image to work is to use a deep learning-based method to direct infer depth. Usually, the deep learning-based approaches are all based on python, so if you only familiar with **python**, then this is the approach that you should go for. If the image is small enough, i think it is possible for **realtime** performance. There are many of this kind of work using CAFFE, TF, TORCH etc. you can search on git hub for more option. The one I posted here is what i used recently

[image]

reference:
Godard, Clément, et al. "Digging into self-supervised monocular depth estimation." Proceedings of the IEEE international conference on computer vision. 2019.

Source code: https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2

**The other way** is to use a large FOV video for a single camera-based SLAM. This one has various constraints such as need good features, large FOV, slow motion, etc.  You can find many of this work such as DTAM, LSDSLAM, DSO, etc. There are a couple of other packages from HKUST or ETH that does the mapping given the position(e.g if you have GPS/compass), some of the famous names are REMODE+SVO open_quadtree_mapping etc.

One typical example for  a single camera-based SLAM would be LSDSLAM. It is a **realtime** SLAM.

This one is implemented based on ROS-C++, I remember they do publish the depth image. And you can write a **python** node to subscribe to the depth directly or the global optimized point cloud and project it into a depth map of any view angle.

[image]

reference: Engel, Jakob, Thomas Schöps, and Daniel Cremers. "LSD-SLAM: Large-scale direct monocular SLAM." European conference on computer vision. Springer, Cham, 2014.

source code: https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam